# Waiting for page full load using Scrapy framework

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape some data from this [website](https://openweathermap.org/city/625665).

For data scraping I'm using Scrapy framework.

I inspected the webpage and found out that the data I want to extract has the following XPath:

`//*[@id="weather-widget"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h2`

When I scraped the webpage and started looking through its content I found out that the page does not contain an element with the XPath above.

Is it possible to somehow wait for the page to load and extract the values that I need?

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not finding the data you are looking for because it's loaded from another request. you can either use something like selenium or puppeteer to load the full page, Or you can try to open send the request directly to the api to get the data.

For the site you provided the request that generates the data is something similar to

`https://openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=625665&appid=439d4b804bc8187953eb36d2a8c26a02`

you can confirm it by opening `DevTools > Network tab` and refresh the page to see the request